# Is Google Guava Bloom Filter thread safe?

Tags: java, guava

Is the guava bloom filter in 18.0 thread safe. On other words, can I have multiple threads share a Bloom Filter instance and use myBloomInstance.mightContain and myBloomInstance.put concurrently.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

No, you must synchronize.

You can split in into a few parts if you need concurrency. There's 
`com.google.common.util.concurrent.Striped` which makes it pretty easy.

And as always, you can fill it and only read it in another thread, assuming that you do a *save publication*.

#### Update

The `BloomFilter` is thread-safe in the current Guava version:
https://github.com/google/guava/commit/6092a4a8b1087f92d0c3169b9e96d53c54ca95c4